# Android camera frezes

Tags: android, android-camera

I have made one project in which I work with android camera API. But on old android phones like (Samsung galaxy S) i have annoying issue. When I try to take photo my application freezes and after few seconds ANR dialog appears. After I kill my program camera is still blocked and I cannot use it even from system camera application, only phone reboot helped me.
Last log message thet I received is:

```
QualcommCameraHardware(133): runframethread: waiting for preview  thread to complete.
```

On new devices everything works fine, how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it usually is the answer was simple.
After some time of browsing Internet I found native code that post last log message:

```
//waiting for preview thread to complete before clearing of the buffers
 mPreviewThreadWaitLock.lock();
 while (mPreviewThreadRunning) {
     LOGI("runframethread: waiting for preview  thread to complete.");
     mPreviewThreadWait.wait(mPreviewThreadWaitLock);
     LOGI("initPreview: old preview thread completed.");
 }
 mPreviewThreadWaitLock.unlock();
```

According to this code I try to call manually `Camera.stopPreview();` before each call to `camera.takePicture(null, null, null, pictureCallback);` and it works.

**UPDATE**
It appears that solution with `Camera.stopPreview();` wont work on devices with new camera drivers because normally you cannot take picture with stopped preview. But instead of using `Camera.stopPreview();` I try simply to remove `onPreviewCallback` with `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);` and it works on all devices that I have tested with old and new camera drivers !!!

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
camera.takePicture(null, null, null, pictureCallback);
```